# Display Additional Text in My Account's Dashboard for Specific User Roles for WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, if-statement, woocommerce, user-roles

My IF statement is not correctly filtering the user roles after they've logged in to display additional text within the dashboard for Corporate/Partner users.

I'm making this edit directly in dashboard.php from woocommerce/templates/myaccount

```
<p>
    <?php
      if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
         $user = wp_get_current_user();
         $role = ( array ) $user->roles;
      if($role[0]=="Corporate"||"Partner")
         printf('Bulk rate discount is available at listed rates: ');
        }
    ?>
</p>
```

What I've tried:
The text showed regardless of the user's role. This means that the check failed. I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Upon changing the statement to only

```
if($role[0]=="Corporate")
```

The text does not show up at all.

What I was expecting:
When the user logs in, it should recognize the roles, and show the text I've included if they are relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code:
If you want to check the logged in user role, then uncomment the echo line.

```
        global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    //echo $user_role;

      if($user_role =="corporate" || $user_role == "partner")
         printf('Bulk rate discount is available at listed rates: ');
```

I have tested it and it's working.
Please let me know if you find any issue with the code

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind & swift help, Kairav. It indeed works as intended.  However, I found this in the log:

`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function user_is_logged_in()`

Could you help me understand why this happens, and what I can do to negate this?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Pleas check it.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function user_is_logged_in() --- This is because dashboard.php file works with the login flow. So no need to write this function: user_is_logged_in()

Comment: Understood. No errors after the updated code. Much appreciated, Kairav.